# compare and contrast, comparison and?

Tags: word-choice

Just like the title says, when I say compare and contrast, what is the equivalent of the word contrast if I say comparison.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 2):

Verbs: *compare* and *contrast*.
Nouns: *comparison* and *contrast*.

Comment: Upvoted with misgivings. It's a trivial "general reference" question, but I still think you should have included a link to online definitions - cite authoritative sources, and all that.

Comment: Like many two-syllable verbs with zero-derived nominalizations, the two words compare (N) and compare (V) are pronounced differently. The verb is stressed on the second syllable, while the noun is stressed on the first.

So the difference would be 
/kəm'pɛr ṇ kən'træst/ as verbs
vs
/kəm'pɛrəsən ṇ 'kantræst/ as nouns.

Comment: +1 for the concept of differentiated pronunciation. However, you initially cite *compare* instead of *contrast*.